# Creating a set of Unique Values from Dictionary effciiently

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, set

I am new to python programming.
I have a Dictionary of Objects which are queried from MongoDB. This Document contains a **Movie ID** and the relevant **Tweets** regarding the movie.
The Movie_ids would be repeating and I wanted to create a SET of Unique Movie_ids . The current code that I wrote is as follows:

```
client = MongoClient()     
discoverMovies = client['discovermovies']
tweets = discoverMovies.tweetdbs.find()
unique_movie = set()
for tweet in tweets:
     unique_movie.add(tweet.get("movie_id"))
for movie in unique_movie:
     print(movie)
```

My **Question** is , is there a more efficient way to achieve the same, i.e getting a unique set from Dictionary where the Dictionary contains other key value pairs as well?

Thanks
Sourav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `tweet` is your dictionary, `set(tweet.values())` will be as efficient as it can get.

A general example:

```
print set({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}.values())
# {1, 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, since I am querying MongoDB I realized  lately that i can use distinct(key)
Get a list of distinct values for key among all documents in the result set of this query.